# Remove page number from the first page of bibliography

Tags: biblatex, header-footer

I'm writing a thesis and I want to remove the page number of the first page of bibliography.
I tried

```
\thispagestyle{empty}  
\pagestyle{plain}
```

but it seems not work. I am using

```
\usepackage[style=ieee, sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{ref}
```

Furthermore, I want to remove the page number corresponding to Bibliography in Table of Contents but I can't.

Can anyone help me?
Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The command `\bibsetup` is available for inserting code that is to be run at the start of the bibliography.  So in this case, you can write

```
\renewcommand{\bibsetup}{\thispagestyle{empty}}
```

to clear that the page number for that page, or

```
\renewcommand{\bibsetup}{\thispagestyle{empty}\pagestyle{plain}}
```

to also set the pagestyle for the subsequent pages.

Comment: I used `\bibsetup{\thispagestyle{empty}\pagestyle{empty}}
\printbibliography[title=References]` The first page of Bibliography still has the page number but the next pages does not have it

Comment: I am sorry, the `\renewcommand` got omitted from my code.  I have now corrected my answer.  By the way, I have tested it using `article` class.

Comment: Yes, I tried and worked perfectly! Thank you! Now, I am trying to remove the Bibliography page number in TOC.

Comment: @Iuiserta -- Are you expected to remove the bibliography from the ToC?  It is a normal (and useful) thing to have in your table of contents?  If so, you should ask it as a separate question and include what article class you are using along with any packages that might influence how your ToC is constructed.

Comment: Hello jon. What I am trying to do is remove the page number of the Bibliography in TOC. My document class is report and I am not using any package that can influence the TOC.  This is how my TOC is generated:  `\phantomsection \pdfbookmark{Contents}{contents}  \tableofcontents`

Comment: @luiserta See my answer to the separate question you posted at jon's request.  The code there can also be added to the `\bibsetup` command.

Comment: @AndrewSwann - Great answer, thanks. However, after using your command the last page of the bibliography still has the number (and header). Any idea what might be going on? Thanks!

Comment: @Matteo The code is only for removing this on the first page of the bib.  Replace `\pagestyle{plain}` by `\pagestyle{empty}` if want no page numbers throughout the bib.

Comment: @AndrewSwann - Thanks for your prompt reply. Indeed, I used this command `\renewcommand{\bibsetup}{\thispagestyle{empty}\pagestyle{empty}}` right after the `\usepackage[...]{biblatex}` but for whatever reason the very last page of the bibliography has a header and page number, while all the other ones are cleared. This is happening also for the individual bibliographies of each chapter. I am writing a thesis and using the `fancyhdr` package. Should I create an entire new question to explain better? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Matteo Yes, a new question would be appropriate.  It is probably the material afterwards that is changing the page style...

Comment: @AndrewSwann - Here is a [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/534565/apply-empty-style-to-the-entire-bibliography) to my question in case you can provide any help. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `book` or `report` as the documentclass, the easiest way to remove all page numbers from the "chapter" pages (including the first page of toc, tof, bibliography, ...) is to redefine the plain style automatically used in these pages (unless you explicitely indicated otherwise). With the following lines in the preambule you redefine the titlepage style as empty:

```
\makeatletter
\let\ps@plain\ps@empty
\makeatother
```

This way you can also force the plain style to be fancy (by replacing "empty" by "fancy")