# Add chapter to TOC without page number

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering

How can I add a chapter entry to TOC without showing the correspondent page number?
my documentclass is `report` and I am generating my TOC like this:

```
\phantomsection 
\pdfbookmark{\Contents}{contents}
\tableofcontents
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 13):

You could load the `tocloft` package and issue the command `\cftpagenumbersoff{chapter}`. This will suppress the showing of the page numbers of chapter-type entries globally.

To make this change apply to only a single instance of a chapter, you might type

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\cftpagenumbersoff{chapter}}
\chapter{XYZ}
...
\addtocontents{toc}{\cftpagenumberson{chapter}} % to restore the showing of page numbers
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add text to the table of contents using the command `\addtocontents`.  Internally, LaTeX uses a couple of commands to create these entries. So for example to add a line, matching the rest of the contents style for chapters write

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{chapter}{\protect\numberline{}Title of this chapter}{}}
```

note you need to protect commands that should not be expanded.

Here I assuming you do not wish to have the chapter number displayed, as per your [question on bibliographies](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66301/15925).  If you do wish to have a chapter number, it is inserted as the first argument to `\numberline` (one can conviently use `\thechapter` for that).

If you use `hyperref` too, then `\contentsline` takes an extra argument, so either write

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{chapter}{\protect\numberline{}Title of this chapter}{}{}}
```

or

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\contentsline{chapter}{\protect\numberline{\thechapter}Title of this chapter}{}{chapter.\thechapter}}
```

for unnumbered/numbered versions.

Comment: This does cause `! Argument of \contentsline has an extra }.` for me.

Comment: @Zelphir What is your documentclass/tocstyle? The above works with `book`.

Comment: I figured it out somehow. I am using `book` and `hyperref`. I now use: `\cftaddtitleline{toc}{chapter}{<name>}{}` instead. Not quite sure what was wrong before.

Comment: @Zelphir `book`+`hyperref` defines no such command; I have now added code for this situation.  You must be loading some other package.

Comment: I am loading loads of packages for all sorts of things, so you are probably right about that : ) btw. Is there some search engine, where I can input a command and it tells me which packages implement it? Especially for TeX or LaTeX? Using a normal search engine one can find questions about unknown control sequences and this way indirectly figuring it out, but that is not perfect. (I figured out the command comes from `tocloft` this way.)