# Remove appendix page numbers in TOC while using appendix package

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices

I'm using `\usepackage[title,titletoc]{appendix}` and putting my appendices in the appendices environment. I'm trying to remove the appendix page numbers from the TOC.

I've looked at the documentation for the appendix packaged and tried using `\noappendicestocpagenum` without success.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[title,titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

    \tableofcontents
    \clearpage
    \section{first}
    \section{second}
    \pagebreak
    \begin{appendices}

        \section{additional material}
        \setcounter{page}{1}
        \renewcommand{\thepage}{\thesection -\arabic{page}}

        \lipsum

        \pagebreak
        \section{more of it}
        \setcounter{page}{1}
        \renewcommand{\thepage}{\thesection -\arabic{page}}

        \lipsum

    \end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

[image: Page Numbers to be removed]

Advice on better formatting of my page numbers would also be welcome.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: The linked solution does not answer my question as I do not wish to suppress the appendix section numbers, only the page numbers in the TOC. Additionally, this solution does not use the appendix package, which I am using.

Comment: Use http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66437/7561. Add the package `tocloft` and after `appendices` environment do `\addtocontents{toc}{\cftpagenumbersoff{section}}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this solution. Add the package `tocloft` and after appendices environment do `\addtocontents{toc}{\cftpagenumbersoff{section}}`

Your code will be reworked as

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[title,titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

  \tableofcontents
  \clearpage
  \section{first}
  \section{second}
  \pagebreak
  \begin{appendices}
    \addtocontents{toc}{\cftpagenumbersoff{section}}
    \section{additional material}
    \setcounter{page}{1}
    \renewcommand{\thepage}{\thesection -\arabic{page}}

    \lipsum

    \pagebreak
    \section{more of it}
    \setcounter{page}{1}
    \renewcommand{\thepage}{\thesection -\arabic{page}}

    \lipsum

  \end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You'll also need to do the same for `subsection` and `subsubsection`, if you're using them.