# How to add a section to table of contents without numbering?

Tags: sectioning, appendices

I want to add my appendix section to table of contents without page number (but also include dots). I tried any other suggestions in this site but I can't overcome.

```
Here is my manually created appendix page code

\section*{}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{APPENDIX}
\vspace*{2.1cm}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
\textbf{{\Large APPENDIX}}
\end{center}
```

I use [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/152595/139314) solution but nothing is changed.

Here is my code:

```
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
    \tableofcontents
\end{center}
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{ŞEKİLLER DİZİNİ}

\begin{center}\listoffigures\end{center}
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{ÇİZELGELER DİZİNİ}

\begin{center}\listoftables\end{center}
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{SİMGELER VE KISALTMALAR DİZİNİ}
\begin{center}
    \textbf{SİMGELER VE KISALTMALAR DİZİNİ}
\end{center}
end{document}

%Here I want to create appendices page
\newpage
\begin{appendices}
\addtocontents{toc}{\cftpagenumbersoff{section}}
\begin{center}
    \section{EKLER}
\end{center}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{EKLER}
\vspace*{2.1cm}
\pagestyle{empty}
%\begin{center}
%\textbf{{\Large EKLER}}
%\end{center}
\vskip 0.5 true in
\textbf{EK-1:} Hesaplamaların Yapıldığı 
\textsc{Matlab\textsuperscript{\textregistered}} Kodları
\pagestyle{empty}
\end{appendices}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Why do you do that `\section*`? You do not need it. And please complete your code example so that it's compilable.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! [Remove appendix page numbers in TOC while using appendix package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/239162/124842) maybe could help you.- But for furtherhelp we need a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I edited the original post. I am newbie sorry.