# How to remove page number of \chapter and allow page numbers of \chapter* in Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, page-numbering

How can I remove page number of `\chapter` yet allow page numbers of `\chapter*` in the Table of Contents within using the `report` class?

Comment: I take it you mean the number shown on the the first page of the chapter. This depends on the document class, but most use \thispagestyle{plain} on the first page of the chapter.  You might try using \thispagestyle{empty} after \chapter, or you can redefine plain style to not show the page number, or redefine \chapter to use \thispagestyle{empty}.

Answer (score 2):

In order to distinguish between the management of `\chapter` and `\chapter*` in the ToC, I've created two different hangling macros. The first is the traditional `\l@chapter` which I've replaced with something that discards its second argument - the page number. The second (for `\chapter*`) replicates what is done for `\l@chapter` (or `\chapter`) but just calls it `\l@schapter`.

The following minimal example has two chapters. The first is a regular `\chapter`, while the second is a `\chapter*`. The latter requires a manual insertion into the ToC using an `schapter` type (see [Creating unnumbered chapters/sections (plus adding them to the ToC and/or header)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35433/5764)).

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\makeatletter
\let\l@schapter\l@chapter % Copy \l@chapter into \l@schapter
\let\old@l@chapter\l@chapter % Copy \l@chapter into \old@l@chapter
\renewcommand{\l@chapter}[2]{\old@l@chapter{#1}{}}% Discard second argument of \l@chapter
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{A chapter}

\chapter*{Another chapter}
\addcontentsline{toc}{schapter}{Another chapter}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to achieve what I think you are looking for, using `nameref`, `tocloft` and `etoolbox`.

It uses `nameref` to add the unnumbered chapters to the table of contents. After `\chapter*` you can see there are two lines I've added.

To remove the page numbers from numbered `\chapter` in the ToC, I've used `tocloft` and the `\cftpagenumbersoff{chapter}` and `\cftpagenumberson{chapter}` commands. Using `etoolbox` I've added `\cftpagenumbersoff{chapter}` before instances of `\chapter` and added `\cftpagenumberson{chapter}` immediately afterwards to restore numbering. Note that you have to use `\@chapter` to specifically apply this to `\chapter` only and not `\chapter*`.

**Sources:**

[Adding unnumbered sections to TOC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11668/adding-unnumbered-sections-to-toc)

[Add chapter to TOC without page number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66430/add-chapter-to-toc-without-page-number)

[Is it possible to add a command at the beginning of a chapter?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/298031/is-it-possible-to-add-a-command-at-the-beginning-of-a-chapter)

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\pretocmd{\@chapter}{% <--- IMPORTANT
\addtocontents{toc}{\cftpagenumbersoff{chapter}}% <--- IMPORTANT
}{}{}
\apptocmd{\@chapter}{% <--- IMPORTANT
\addtocontents{toc}{\cftpagenumberson{chapter}}% <--- IMPORTANT
}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\chapter{A chapter}

\chapter*{Another chapter}
\label{chap:test}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\nameref{chap:test}}

\chapter{And another chapter}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Milo. In addition to the solution you provided here, I am very grateful, but I also want the numbered chapters to be in the form CHAPTER ONE: INTRODUCTION  in the table of content.

Comment: It's better if you ask this as a separate question on the site.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found an answer to my question:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath,amsthm,geometry} %enumerate% directly loaded from texstudio
\usepackage{lipsum} % for generating dummy texts
\usepackage{tocloft}  %for table of contents and list of figure formatting
\usepackage{fmtcount} % for textual representation of numbers
\usepackage{etoolbox} % for changing internal parameters of latex
\usepackage{fancyhdr}  % for pagestyles
\usepackage{times}    % for times new roman font
\usepackage[linktoc=all]{hyperref}   % for link to chapter and section. if you comment hyperref package, you must also comment all the \phantomsection in this code.
\usepackage{tikz} % for drawing
\usepackage{titletoc} %for table of content formatting

%%% this code centred, adjust chapters' distance from the title and convert chapter 1 to chapter one
    \makeatletter  
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
    \vspace*{-60\p@}% default: 50pt % vertical distance between chapter and top of page
    {\parindent \z@ \centering \normalfont% default: \raggedright
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \NUMBERstring{chapter}%\the
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@% default: 20\p@  % vertical distance between chapter and title below it
        \fi
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
        \vskip 40\p@
}}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
    \vspace*{-80\p@}% default: 50pt % vertical distance between unnumbered chapter and top of page
    {\parindent \z@ \centering% default: \raggedright
        \normalfont
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \Huge \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
        \vskip 40\p@
}}
\makeatother



%%% this code changes the names of contets, list of figures,abstract, chapters and references
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\large{Table of Contents}}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{\large{List of Figures}}
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{\large{Abstract}}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{\large{References}}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{\large{CHAPTER}}


%This code centres table of content
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill\Large\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}

%This code centres list of figure
\renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\hfill\Large\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftafterloftitle}{\hfill}

\linespread{1.8}

%this code redefines the chapter format in table of contents
\newlength{\len}
\titlecontents{chapter}[1.2em]{\bfseries}%\bfseries
{\contentslabel[\large{\chaptername} \NUMBERstringnum{\thecontentslabel}:]{3.6em}\settowidth{\len} {Chapter \NUMBERstringnum{\thecontentslabel}}\hspace*{\len}}%]
{\large{\thecontentslabel}\hspace*{-5.1cm}}%\contentslabel[]{}
{\hfill\contentspage}% replace \hfill with \cftdotfill{\cftdotsep} if you want dots in chapters in toc


% this code for list of figures with figure, cation and page.
\renewcommand{\cftafterloftitle}{\hfill{}
    \\[\baselineskip]\mbox{\textbf{Figure}}\hfill{\textbf{Caption}}\hfill{\normalfont \textbf{Page}}}


%this code removes the references label(their numbers) on the reference page
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

    \pagenumbering{roman}

    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancypagestyle{plain} 
    \fancyhf{}
    \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}

\phantomsection 
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}Title Page}
\chapter*{Title}

\newpage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}Certification}

    \chapter*{\large{Certification}}

\newpage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}Dedication}

    \chapter*{\large{Dedication}}


\newpage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}Acknowledgements}

\chapter*{\large{Acknowledgements}}


\newpage

\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}Table of Contents}
\setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{-2.5cm} %to control vertical spacing
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}List of Figures}
\setlength{\cftbeforeloftitleskip}{-2.5cm} %to control vertical spacing
\listoffigures 
\clearpage
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}Abstract}
\chapter*{\large{Abstract}}


\newpage
\phantomsection 
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}Nomenclatures}

    \chapter*{\large{Nomenclatures}}


\newpage  
\pagenumbering{arabic}

%this code redefines the chapter format in table of contents
\titlecontents{chapter}[1.2em]{\bfseries}%\bfseries
{\contentslabel[\large{\chaptername} \NUMBERstringnum{\thecontentslabel}:]{3.6em}\settowidth{\len} {Chapter \NUMBERstringnum{\thecontentslabel}}\hspace*{\len}}%]
{\large{\thecontentslabel}\hspace*{-5.1cm}}%\contentslabel[]{}
{\hfill\cftpagenumbersoff{chapter}}% 

\chapter{\large{INTRODUCTION}}

\fancyhf{}
%\fancyhead[C]{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancypagestyle{plain} 
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
%\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\section{Introduction}

\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\subsection{Subsection 2}


\section{Section 2} 

\chapter{\large{LITERATURE REVIEW}}
\section{Section 1}

\section{Section 2}

 \chapter{\large{RESEARCH METHODOLOGY}}  
\section{Section 1}

\section{Section 2}



 \section{Section 3}

\chapter {\large{RESULTS AND DISCUSSION}}
\section{Section 1}
\section{Section 2}
\section{Section 3}

\chapter {\large{CONCLUSION}}
\section{Summary}
\section{Conclusion}
\section{Recommendation}
\newpage
\phantomsection

%this code redefines the chapter format in table of contents
\titlecontents{chapter}[1.2em]{\bfseries}
{\contentslabel[\large{\chaptername} \NUMBERstringnum{\thecontentslabel}:]{3.6em}\settowidth{\len} {Chapter \NUMBERstringnum{\thecontentslabel}}\hspace*{\len}}%]
{\large{\thecontentslabel}\hspace*{-5.1cm}}
{\hfill\contentspage}%

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{} REFERENCES}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{1} First reference
\bibitem{2} Second reference
\bibitem{3} Third reference
\bibitem{4} Fourth reference
\bibitem{5} Fifth reference
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can somebody help me put the latex code above properly on stack exchange for others to use.

Comment: Can you add some motivation behind your solution?

Comment: To expand on Werner's comment, you've posted ~200 lines of code, but it's not clear which of those lines are necessary for your solution (which unfortunately wasn't all that clear to begin with), and which of those lines are superfluous.  To respond to your comment, you can highlight your code and then click `{}` or type `ctrl-k`.

Comment: Thanks. the code %this code redefines the chapter format in table of contents
\newlength{\len}
\titlecontents{chapter}[1.2em]{\bfseries}%\bfseries
{\contentslabel[\large{\chaptername} \NUMBERstringnum{\thecontentslabel}:]{3.6em}\settowidth{\len} {Chapter \NUMBERstringnum{\thecontentslabel}}\hspace*{\len}}%]
{\large{\thecontentslabel}\hspace*{-5.1cm}}%\contentslabel[]{}
{\hfill\contentspage}

Comment: Thanks. The lines 58 - 62 and 192-195; \newlength{\len}
\titlecontents{chapter}[1.2em]{\bfseries}%\bfseries
{\contentslabel[\large{\chaptername} \NUMBERstringnum{\thecontentslabel}:]{3.6em}\settowidth{\len} {Chapter \NUMBERstringnum{\thecontentslabel}}\hspace*{\len}}%]
{\large{\thecontentslabel}\hspace*{-5.1cm}}%\contentslabel[]{}
{\hfill\contentspage} %   adds page number of chapters  without dots in table of contents   while  lines 140 to 143 removes page number of chapters in table of contents.

Answer (score 0):

Write this code `\addtocontents{toc}{\cftpagenumbersoff{chapter}}` before the chapter one and `\addtocontents{toc}{\cftpagenumberson{chapter}}` before references to get the desired result. Here is a minimal example

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath,amsthm} %enumerate% directly loaded from texstudio
\usepackage[left=38.00mm, right=13.00mm, top=25.00mm, bottom=13.00mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for generating dummy texts
\usepackage{tocloft}  %for table of contents and list of figure formatting
\usepackage{fmtcount} % for textual representation of numbers
\usepackage{etoolbox} % for changing internal parameters of latex
\usepackage{fancyhdr}  % for pagestyles
\usepackage{times}    % for times new roman font
%\usepackage[linktoc=all]{hyperref}   % for link to chapter and section
\usepackage{tikz} % for drawing
%\usepackage{titletoc} %for table of content formatting

%%% this code centred, adjust chapters' distance from the title and convert chapter 1 to chapter one
\makeatletter  
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
    \vspace*{-60\p@}% default: 50pt % vertical distance between chapter and top of page
    {\parindent \z@ \centering \normalfont% default: \raggedright
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \NUMBERstring{chapter}%\the
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@% default: 20\p@  % vertical distance between chapter and title below it
        \fi
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
        \vskip 40\p@
}}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{%
    \vspace*{-70\p@}% default: 50pt % vertical distance between unnumbered chapter and top of page
    {\parindent \z@ \centering% default: \raggedright
        \normalfont
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \Huge \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
        \vskip 40\p@
}}
\makeatother

%% This code rename 1 to CHAPTER ONE in table of contents:
\makeatletter  
\def\@chapter[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
    \refstepcounter{chapter}%
    \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
    {\protect \chaptername~\NUMBERstringnum{\thechapter}:~#1}%
    \else
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
    \fi
    \chaptermark{#1}%
    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
    \if@twocolumn
    \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
    \else
    \@makechapterhead{#2}%
    \@afterheading
    \fi}
\makeatother

%%% this code changes the names of contets, list of figures,abstract, chapters and references
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\large{Table of Contents}}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{\large{List of Figures}}
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{\large{Abstract}}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{\large{References}}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{\large{CHAPTER}}
%\renewcommand{\cftchappresnum}{\chaptername~}

%This code centres table of content
\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hspace*{6cm}\large\bfseries}
%\renewcommand{\cfttoctitlefont}{\hfill\large\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfill}

%This code centres list of figure
\renewcommand{\cftloftitlefont}{\hfill\large\bfseries}
\renewcommand{\cftafterloftitle}{\hfill}

\linespread{1.8}

% this code for list of tables with figure, cation and page.
\renewcommand{\cftafterloftitle}{\hfill{}
    \\[\baselineskip]\mbox{\textbf{Figure}}\hspace*{6cm}{\textbf{Caption}}\hfill{\normalfont \textbf{Page}}}

%this code removes the references label
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@biblabel[1]{}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\titlepage
    \pagenumbering{roman}   

%\phantomsection    
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}Title Page}
\chapter*{Title}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage

%\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}Certification}

    \chapter*{\large{Certification}}

\newpage
%\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}Dedication}

    \chapter*{\large{Dedication}}


\newpage
%\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}Acknowledgements}

\chapter*{\large{Acknowledgements}}

\newpage

%\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}Table of Contents}
\setlength{\cftbeforetoctitleskip}{-2.5cm} %to control vertical spacing
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
%\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}List of Figures}
\setlength{\cftbeforeloftitleskip}{-2.5cm} %to control vertical spacing
\listoffigures 
\clearpage
%\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}Abstract}
\chapter*{\large{Abstract}}

\newpage
%\phantomsection    
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{}Nomenclatures}

    \chapter*{\large{Nomenclatures}}

\newpage  
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\addtocontents{toc}{\cftpagenumbersoff{chapter}}
\chapter{\large{INTRODUCTION}}

\fancyhf{}
%\fancyhead[C]{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancypagestyle{plain} 
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[C]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
%\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\section{Introduction}

\section{Section 1}
\subsection{Subsection 1}
\subsection{Subsection 2}

\section{Section 2} 

\chapter{\large{LITERATURE REVIEW}}
\section{Section 1}

\newpage
%\phantomsection
\addtocontents{toc}{\cftpagenumberson{chapter}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\numberline{} REFERENCES}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{1} First reference
\bibitem{2} Second reference
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is a better code than the one I posted before it. I hope somebody will help me put it in proper format.

Comment: Thank you Stefan Pinnow for putting my code in proper format for this page. I am very grateful. I hope it will be useful for others.