# Apply empty style to the entire bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, memoir, page-numbering, pagestyle

I would like the entire bibliography to have an `empty` page style in my document (which means remove the headers and page numbers).

I used the command `\renewcommand{\bibsetup}{\thispagestyle{empty}\pagestyle{empty}}` from [Remove page number from the first page of bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66301/remove-page-number-from-the-first-page-of-bibliography/) which successfully removes the style from the first and all subsequent pages of the bibliography **except for the last page**.

I created a minimal working example that produces the following output:

[image]

As you can see, the first page of the references has no style. However, the second page (which in this case is the last one) has the page number at the bottom.

Note that this happens also *i)* if I have more than just two bibliography pages, and *ii)* for the intermediate bibliographies at the end of each of my chapters.

I am writing a thesis (`memoir` class) and am using the `fancyhdr` package, in case this is relevant.

Any suggestion on what might be going on? Thanks a lot!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=ieee,
    citestyle=numeric-comp,
    backrefstyle = none
]{biblatex}

\renewcommand{\bibsetup}{\thispagestyle{empty}\pagestyle{empty}}

\addbibresource{bibli.bib}

\title{Minimal working example}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
coordinates~\cite{li20143d,pavllo20193d}, predictions~\cite{pavlakos2016coarse,varol2018bodynet}, models~\cite{tome2017lifting} encoding~\cite{kanazawa2018end,bogo2016keep} information~\cite{zhou2017towards,habibie2019wild} training~\cite{rhodin2018learning,qiu2019cross}

a \cite{andriluka20142d,lin2014microsoft} markers \cite{sigal2010humaneva,h36m_pami} multi \cite{Joo_2015_ICCV,mehta2017monocular} cameras~\cite{shu2016learning} free~\cite{chen2016synthesizing,varol2017learning,tome2019xr} camera~\cite{taylor2000reconstruction,bourdev2009poselets,pavlakos2018ordinal,ronchi2018s} camera \cite{rhodin2018unsupervised} point \cite{sermanet2017time,mitra2019multiview}


\newpage
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]

\end{document}
```

Comment: It's not immediately obvious why pages after the first carry a page number.  This should have been suppressed by `\pagestyle{empty}`.  Try adding an extra line between `\newpage` and `\printbibliography`.  If that doesn't work, debugging will have to be undertaken in `article.cls` and `biblatex.sty`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be regarded as a fault with the standard `bibliography` environment in `biblatex`.  In an `article` class what you are asking is no really appropriate as the bibliography is not designed to start on a separate page.  But your problem persists in `book` and `memoir`, and the solution below works in all cases.
Namely, I patch (updated: better than previous redefining) the default `biblatex` default version of the `bibliography` environment to add a `\clearpage` efter the end of the bibliography's internal `list` environment.

[image: sample output]

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=ieee,
    citestyle=numeric-comp,
    backrefstyle = none
]{biblatex}

\renewcommand{\bibsetup}{\thispagestyle{empty}\pagestyle{empty}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\blx@endenv@bibliography}{\endlist}{\endlist\clearpage}{}{}
\makeatother

\title{Minimal working example}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\nocite{*}

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]

\end{document}
```

If you are in an `article` class, you will want to add `\clearpage` before `\printbibliography`

Comment: The definition of `\defbibenvironment{bibliography}` may depend on the style. With `ieee` or a `numeric` style the default environment looks a bit different from the stub in `biblatex.sty`. In particular the definition shown here removes the citation numbers from the bibliography, which is probably not desired.

Comment: @moewe Thanks - changed to a patch instead.

Comment: @AndrewSwann - This worked perfectly on both the subheading bibliography and the intoc bibliography. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

I would just separate the heading from the bibliography and put your page style commands in between:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[style=ieee, citestyle=numeric-comp, backrefstyle=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\nocite{*}
\printbibheading[heading=bibintoc]
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{empty}
\printbibliography[heading=none]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think I saw an issue like this before, but I can't find it now. If I remember correctly, the problem basically was that `\bibsetup` is executed inside a group and that the last page takes its style from outside the group (as that is the style that is active at the end of the page, I presume).

Comment: @David Thanks for the great answer! It worked great for the final bibliography! However, the subheading bibs still have the number in the last page. I changed `\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]` with `\printbibheading[heading=subbibliography]
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{empty}
\printbibliography[heading=none]`, but it didn't work. Any suggestions? Thanks.