# How to make the second page empty

Tags: biblatex, emptypage

I am a beginner in Latex and I have a problem such as:

I was able to make the first and third pages of the bibliographer empty, but I cannot make the second page empty.

An idea please.

This is the tex code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,openany]{book}
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{chngcntr}   
\usepackage{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}  
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}
\newcommand{\printmyminitoc}{
\noindent\hspace{0cm}\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[rounded corners,align=left,fill=white,blur shadow={shadow blur steps=5},inner sep=5mm]{%
\color{black}%
\begin{minipage}{15cm}%minipage trick
\textbf{\Large Contents}\\
\rule{\textwidth}{1.5pt}
\printcontents[chapters]{}{1}{}
\end{minipage}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\ \vspace{1cm} \\}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor=green, citecolor=red, linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{titleps}
\newpagestyle{mine}{
\headrule
\sethead{\itshape\chaptername\thechapter}{}{\itshape\chaptertitle}
\footrule
\setfoot{}{\thepage}{}
}
\renewpagestyle{plain}{
\setfoot{}{}{\thepage}}
\pagestyle{mine}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{graphicx}           
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{indentfirst}            
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages} 
\usepackage{fancybox}
%\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber, % bibtex  % bibtex or biber (prefered)
  natbib=true,
  style=numeric,
  sorting=nty  % none, nty % no sorting or standard sorting
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliogra.bib}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{dsfont} 
\usepackage{lastpage} 
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2.75cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[Bjornstrup]{fncychap}
\usepackage{hyperref}  
\definecolor{9ahwi}{rgb}{0.5, 0.1, 0.005}
\definecolor{khdar}{rgb}{0.0, 0.5, 0.8}
\definecolor{ocre}{RGB}{243,102,25}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{plain}
\chapter{Bib}
\cite{Bal89}\cite{DeB86}\cite{Dil93}\cite{Gue97}\cite{Kru00}\cite{Bal90}\cite{Kom67}\cite{Bal96}\cite{Amr92}\\\cite{Ord66}\cite{Hes90}\cite{Hes02}\cite{Hes00}\cite{Hes91}\cite{Lev76}\cite{Mol05}\cite{Ion69}\cite{Val07}\\\cite{Rud91}\cite{Les16}\cite{Bre10}\cite{Sho97}\cite{Die77}\cite{Gio13}\cite{Ric75}\cite{Cha77}\cite{Dan13}\\\cite{Mau75}\cite{Pap02}\cite{Cha99}\cite{Sch70}\cite{Sch86}\cite{Ben15}\cite{Gar79}\cite{Bae72}\cite{Kak39}\cite{Nis63}
\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliographie}
\newpage
\printbibliography
\thispagestyle{plain}\thispagestyle{plain}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Add `\pagestyle{plain}` before `\printbibliography`, and delete the (useless) `\thispagestyle{plain}` after `\printbibliography`.

Comment: This is a bit more tricky than it is supposed to be. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/534565/35864.

Comment: In my tests the answers in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/534565/35864 worked in the MWE from this question as well, so I would be inclined to vote to close this question as a duplicate. Did you manage to resolved your issue? If not, what difficulties did you have and what did you try?