# How to cross-reference the (whole) bibliography?

Tags: biblatex, hyperref, cross-referencing, ref

A simple question, but I was unable to find it on Stackexchange here or somewhere else.

**I want to cross-reference the header generated by `\printbibliography`, i.e. not a specific entry but just the title/starting page.**

How can I do that?

I do use it like this:

```
\printbibliography[title={Quellenverzeichnis}, heading=subbibnumbered]
```

The problem is the package generates its heading automatically, so I cannot just place a `\label` there and refer to that.

Basically, I just want to do what's needed so I can use the usual `\ref`, `\hyperref`,`\autoref`, [`\fullref`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/121871/98645) etc.

And I also have not found anything in the [biblatex docs](http://www.texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/biblatex/biblatex.pdf) (page 88 ff. aka sec. 3.7.2 it starts to talk about the `\printbibliography` command.).

Comment: What exactly is the use case you have in mind? Is writing something such as "As is noted in the *Quellenverzeichnis* at the end of this article, ..." not clear enough? Are you concerned that if readers can't click on a link that takes them to the first page of the formatted bibliography, they won't be able to find the bibliography?

Comment: Well… the use case is I do [list some files as local copies for some sources in the bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/548416/98645) and I do want to add a note in the appendix that says "The local copies that are referenced in the _Quellenverzeichnis_  are placed in the directory … in the accompanying ZIP/USB drive [etc.]".
In any case, even in your sentence I would find it very useful if the term "bibliography" could already link to the page where this is found. If I have `hyperref`, why not make use of it?

Comment: Might your readers be better served if you stated the individual bibliographic entries (using the usual `\cite`-type commands) for which electronic copies are made available on some device? The mere fact that your paper contains a *Quellenverzeichnis* needn't be demonstrated by providing a suitable hyperlink, does it?

Comment: It's more of a requirement, so no. It's offline copies of files I actually can already link to, see the linked question). Anyway, it's slightly off-topic for this question, so see the question I've linked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Since v3.16 of biblatex](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/commit/853d8e92dd8cbfb2fd46b061b629fa6f6db4e4c4) you now can use `label` .

Example and so on copied from [the issue/feature request](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/1036), so all credits goes to [@moewew](https://github.com/moewew), who also implemented this.

Here an example:

```latex
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\autocite{sigfridsson}

\Cref{biblabel}

\printbibliography[heading=bibnumbered, label=biblabel]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah @moewe sorry just now saw you are here too. If you want to get the credits for this new updated answer, feel free to repost it and I'll accept that.

Answer (score 3):

Weirdly, I can't find an obvious way of doing this.

Here's an option which prints the heading, then inserts the label, then prints the rest of the bibliography. For some reason unknown to me, the `\@currentlabel` isn't updated by `\printbibheading`, so I need the hack to decrement the subsection counter, then increment it using `\refstepcounter`.

I'm left thinking there must be a better option.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\section{Here}
\subsection{There}
Page \pageref{bib}. Section \ref{bib}.
\nocite{westfahl:space,aksin}
\printbibheading[title=Quellenverzeichnis, heading=subbibnumbered]
\addtocounter{subsection}{-1}
\refstepcounter{subsection}
\label{bib}
\printbibliography[heading=none]
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: The assignment of `\@currentlabel` is always local. Since `\printbibheading` is processed in a group (to make sure the options don't spill out), `\@currentlabel` can't leave the group.

Comment: The grouping is the same issue as https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/534569/35864

Comment: @moewe oh yes, I should have remembered that.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are already explicitly give the title of your bibliography, you can just sneak in a `\label` there.

With David Purton's MWE and the obvious changes

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\section{Here}
\subsection{There}
Page \pageref{bib}. Section \ref{bib}.
\nocite{sigfridsson,worman}

\printbibliography[title={Quellenverzeichnis\label{bib}}, heading=subbibnumbered]
\end{document}
```

[image: Page 1. Section 1.2.]

If you'd like a solution that automatically selects 'References' or 'Bibliography' depending on the class, you can try

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\reforbibname}{%
  \ifodd\abx@classtype\relax
    \bibname
  \else
    \refname
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{Here}
\subsection{There}
Page \pageref{bib}. Section \ref{bib}.
\nocite{sigfridsson,worman}

\printbibliography[title={\reforbibname\label{bib}}, heading=subbibnumbered]
\end{document}
```

The internal command `\abx@classtype` is used by `biblatex` to detect certain classes. Conveniently, the 'even classes' are `article`-like and use `\refname`, the 'odd classes' are `report`/`book`-like and use `\bibname`.

Note that this does not take into account possible changes of the default title in bibliography heading definitions.

---

An alternative would be to include the `\label` directly in the bibliography heading definition. In this case that would be

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\defbibheading{subbibnumbered:link}[\refname]{%
  \subsection{#1}%
  \label{bib}}

\begin{document}
\section{Here}
\subsection{There}
Page \pageref{bib}. Section \ref{bib}.
\nocite{sigfridsson,worman}

\printbibliography[heading=subbibnumbered:link]
\end{document}
```

(of course you could overwrite the bibheading `subbibnumbered` if you like, but since the label is hard-coded in the heading, it may be better to choose a unique name to avoid using it twice.) In any case, this requires you to know/copy the original definition of the bibliography heading used in your document.

Comment: And if I did not defined it – I guess there is some macro I could use to keep the default title?

Comment: But yeah, fun, but a _really_ hacky/"workaroundish" solution…

Comment: @rugk `title={\refname\label{bib}}` or `title={\bibname\label{bib}}`. The only other option I see is to integrate the `\label` directly into the bibliography heading as defined with `\defbibheading`. But the code there is usually much longer, so this solution here seems quicker.

Comment: @rugk That all said, it would certainly be possible to add an option to `\printbibliography` to set a `label` after the heading. Implementing it for/in this answer would result in something I'd see as much more hacky than what I presented here so far, because it would involve messing with many, many internal commands. But if you think that would be useful you can always ask that it be implemented officially: Just go to https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues and open an issue.

Comment: Yeah, indeed, fine. (After all, having a label assigned by default or so would be enough) I've asked for that here: https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/1036